# How to check status of Ethernet port on remote server using Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible

I want to check the status of Ethernet port which is on remote host . I want to whether it is up

Comment: Hi, welcome here. Your question severely lacks the details required to answer it. Please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question the information you are looking for is [gathered together with the facts of the host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html).

```
  gather_facts: yes

- name: Show facts
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

It will contain information from the interfaces in general, in example if it is active.

```
...
"eth0": {
            "active": true,
            "device": "eth0",
            "features": {
...
```

I will leave further reading up to you. You may find useful information under

- [How to enumerate network interfaces in Ansible?](https://serverfault.com/questions/768470/)
- [How to loop through interface facts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/762079/)